# convert node/id to node/path-alias in content body

Tags: 8, path-aliases, uri

I added a link to a content body from ck editor as `/node/7`. When viewing this page I want to show `www.sitename.com/example/alias`.

This is working fine in drupal 7 (earlier version of my site), but not sure which module does this work.

I have installed `pathauto`, `redirect`, `pathologic` modules. I also configured the text format at `admin/config/content/formats` and set pathologic filter as first priority. But no luck.

After installed redirect module, if I hit `node/7` in browser it automatically redirect to expected alias. But I want is the content page should show only `url alias` even If entered `/node/7` in ckeditor.

Am I missing any configurations in any of the above module? or am I missing any module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a hook in `Pathologic` module as `hook_pathologic_alter` and I used it to convert node path to URL alias.

I used this hook as follows

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathologic_alter().
 */
function mymodule_pathologic_alter(&$url_params, &$parts, &$cached_settings){
    if ($parts['path'] != '<front>') {

        //get the alias for the path and assign it in path
        $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/'.$url_params['path']);

        //Url::fromUri which Pathologic uses need a path without slash at first, so trim it
        $url_params['path'] = ltrim($alias, '/');
    }
}
```

This converts a node path to alias and pass it, so Pathologic will form a URL with alias.